# BigQuery returns No Matching Signature

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to run a query on BigQuery console which looks like this

`where created > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 7 day)`

The error I got was

`No matching signature for operator > for argument types: TIMESTAMP, DATE. Supported signatures: ANY > ANY at [3:7]`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the `>` operator to compare two different types, timestamp and date, which is giving you an error. If you want to look seven days in the past, you would use this filter:

```
where created > TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), interval 7 day)
```

If you want to look seven days in the past, but only return rows starting at UTC midnight, you would use this filter:

```
where DATE(created) > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 7 day)
```

The difference is that the first filter compares actual timestamps, which includes the time of day, whereas the second compares dates, which don't have a time part.